# Why is sqlQuery from RODBC not always returning the same data when querying an Impala DB?

Tags: r, impala, rodbc

I'm trying to get some data from an Impala database using the sqlQuery function from the RODBC package. The results I get changes from one execution of a query to another execution of the exact same query.

The data.frame I get doesn't always have the same number of rows:

```
library("RODBC")
conn <- odbcConnect("Cloudera Impala DSN;host=mydb;port=21050")    
df<-sqlQuery(conn, "select * from hydrau.hydr where flight= 'V0051'")
dim(df)
[1] 26600   220
df<-sqlQuery(conn, "select * from hydrau.hydr where flight= 'V0051'")
dim(df)
[1] 142561   220
df<-sqlQuery(conn, "select * from hydrau.hydr where flight= 'V0051'")
dim(df)
[1] 23500   220
```

This query should in fact return a 142561 x 220 data frame.

On the other hand, the following query always return the same (correct) result :

```
sqlQuery(conn, "select count(*) from hydr where flight= 'V0051' ")
  count(*)
1   142561
```

Comment: Are you using 32bit or 64bit ODBC?

Comment: @GeorgeDontas 64bit

Comment: Have you tried setting the `believeNRows` argument to `FALSE`?

Comment: @eminik Yes I did try that, but it didn't change anything. By the way, isn't it weird that this argument even exists ? Why does the the number of rows returned by the ODBC connection shouldn't be believable ?

Comment: I think I had a similar problem (connecting to another database) with 64bit, and now I'm using 32bit.

Comment: @GeorgeDontas Well I tried to follow your advice, but know I get this error : "Can't open lib '/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/32/libclouderaimpalaodbc32.so' : file not found" when calling `odbcConnect`
although this file exists at the indicated path, and `file.exists("/opt/cloudera/impalaodbc/lib/32/libclouderaimpalaodbc32.so")` returns `TRUE`

Comment: I had this exact same thing happen to me, plus more, with the RODBC package.  Not only did the number of rows returned vary at random in some cases, the data I did get was wrong in some rows.  It was like the data was shifted by a row for some variables, I've never seen anything like it.  Even tried 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC drivers and same result.  Ran the exact same query in other programs and it worked fine.  Solution in R was to switch to the DBI package and I'll probably never use the RODBC package again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem was that Impala didn't have enough memory to perform well.

Comment: How you found that impala didn't had enough memory to perform well?